# How to calculate area of intersection of region?

Tags: matlab

I know matlab is powerful.

I wanted to know if it's possible to do the following:

I have 3 areas.

One is a rectangle, one is a triangle, and one is a parabola.

I know limit of rectangle, triangle, and equation of parabola.

Is that possible to trace them on a graph and have the surface covered by all of them?

Comment: How are they represented? Matrix containing points?

Comment: I'm open to suggestion... I'm kinda searching possibility... I wondered if there was a tool to just give equation like y = x^2 and it would draw everything?

Comment: https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18173-polygon-intersection

Comment: look for 'feval' and 'fplot' functions. example: y=@(x) x+sin(x); fplot(y, [0 2*pi])

Comment: I don't know matlab, but I found function to find intersection: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.intersect.html